# Command Line For Loop returns path that is missing last subdirectory

Tags: for-loop, recursion, command-line, subdirectory

I'm trying to use a For Loop to recursively extract all zip files in a folder with multiple levels and even zips within zips. When I run it I get an error message because the last sub directory is blank so it looks like C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\testing\\ and says that it cannot create output directory. I had thought I had had this working earlier but I guess I missed something. Thanks for any and all help!

Here is what I'm running:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\testing\" %I IN (*.zip) DO (7z x "%I" -aou -o\"%~dpI\" && del \"%~fI\")
```

Comment: As per https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/  use `-o"%~dpI"` (remove backslashes). Do the same in `del "%~fI"`

Comment: Ugh. You're my hero. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there all `\"` are survivals of escaping sequences in your command as if it would call from within some another program. No such need (and even harmful) in pure `cmd`.

As per [7-zip Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/) use `-o"%~dpI"` (remove backslashes); do the same in `del "%~fI"` as follows

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\testing\" %I IN (*.zip) DO (7z x "%I" -aou -o"%~dpI" && del "%~fI")
```